# Assign weights to observations based on date difference and sequence condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I already asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570717/find-previous-row-with-the-same-id-and-condition-on-column-value-to-assign-weigh) on the same problem and [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) helped a lot.

However my logic on weights assignment was wrong.

I need to form the following dataframe w/ `weight` column:

```
    id      date        status    weight   diff_in_days  comment
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0    2     2019-02-03   reserve   0.003         0       1 / diff_days
1    2     2019-12-31   reserve   0.001       331       since diff to next is 1 day 
2    2     2020-01-01   reserve    0.9          1       since the next date status is sold   
3    2     2020-01-02   sold        1           1       sold
4    3     2020-01-03   reserve   0.001         0       since diff to next is 1 day
5    4     2020-01-03   booked     0.9          0       since the next date status is sold
6    3     2020-02-04   reserve    0.9          1       since the next date status is sold
7    4     2020-02-06   sold        1           3       sold
7    3     2020-02-07   sold        1           3       sold
```

To make `diff_in_days` column I use:

`df['diff_in_days'] = df.groupby('flat_id')['date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0)`

**Is there a way to implement this preudo-code without for-loop**:

```
for i in df.iterrows():
    df['weight'][i] = 1 / df['diff_in_days'][i+1]
if df['status'][i+1] == 'sold' (for each flat_id):
    df['weight'][i] = 0.9
if df['status'][i] == 'sold':
    df['weight'][i] = 1
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I was not able to modify @mozway code without using for-loop to assign diff to previous date.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it like this:

```
df.sort_values(['flat_id', 'date'], inplace=True)
```

find diff in days between dates for `flat_id`s and shift it one row back

```
s = df.groupby(['flat_id']['date'].diff().dt.days.shift(-1)
```

assign weights for `flat_id`s with `status == 'sold'`

```
df['weight'] = np.where(df['status'].eq('sold'),s.max()+10, s.fillna(0))
```

now find rows with `status == sold` and shift back one row to find it's predecessors

```
s1 = df["status"].eq("sold").shift(-1)
s1 = s1.fillna(False)
```

assign them second maximum weights

```
df.loc[s1, "weight"] = s.max()+5
df["weight"].ffill(inplace=True)
```

final dataframe

```
    flat_id date    status  weight
4   2   2019-02-04  reserve 331.0
0   2   2020-01-01  reserve 336.0
1   2   2020-01-02  sold    341.0
2   3   2020-01-03  reserve 1.0
5   3   2020-01-04  reserve 336.0
7   3   2020-02-07  sold    341.0
3   4   2020-01-03  booked  336.0
6   4   2020-02-06  sold    341.0
```